# PHP set browser agent with fsockopen/cURL

Tags: php, curl, fsockopen, web-crawler

I've written a crawler, which apparently gets blocked by some sites. What I would like to do is fetch pages with a fake user agent ID (Something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:23:00`). Note that `fsockopen()` does not support that, so I'm trying to do that a different way.

Here is my code:

```
$sock = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Then below that, here is what I'm doing with the pointer:

```
    $request  = "HEAD "  . $path . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
    $request .= 'Host: ' . $host . "\r\n"; 
    $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
    fwrite($sock, $request);
```

Again, how do I set a fake browser agent? Can I set it in the `$request` string?

Comment: You need to send a header called `User-Agent` with whatever browser string in order to set the user agent.

Comment: If you state that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

With fsockopen, you can add the User Agent like you did for the others Headers options :

```
$sock = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$request  = "HEAD "  . $path . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
$request .= 'Host: ' . $host . "\r\n"; 
$request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:23:00\r\n";
$request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 


fwrite($sock, $request);
```

Tested with PHP5.3

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. As great as cURL is and all that, this is the only answer which explains how to do this with fsockopen(), like OP specifically asked for.  (It also helped me, since sometimes there are reasons you can't use cURL...)

Answer (score 1):

If you use php cURL (as you suggested in your tags), you should be able to do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:23:00'));
```

Comment: i needed a bit more to get the server to accept my code coming from a php scraper.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $content;
$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
```